# SQL query multiple tables to find a corresponding/related value

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables that all store different info about a transaction

TABLE 1 has 1 column of interest - 'profileID' (unique ID for this transaction)

TABLE 2 has the same 'profileID' and a 'typeID' (unique ID for this transaction type)

TABLE 3 has the same 'typeID' and a 'timestamp' + 'referenceID'

TABLE 4 has 3 columns, 'timestamp'&'referenceID' from TABLE3 and a 'serialNum' column

Given the 'profileID' from TABLE1 I need to retrieve the 'serialNum' from TABLE4 (for use in a stored proc) without any direct route there, so the chain looks something like:

TABLE1<-'profileID'->TABLE2<-'typeID'->TABLE3<-'timestamp','reference'->TABLE4<-'serialNum'

How would i get from TABLE1 to TABLE4 via the profileID, TypeID, Timestamp/reference, to SELECT the serialNum column?

Comment: This is not a forum to solve your programming tasks. What have you tried to solve your problem, and what were the results of your efforts? Hint: You want to join tables, so look at the manual of your DBMS for joins.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what database engine you're using, which may affect things such as how you deal with mixed-case identifiers and the like, but in general you'd do something like

```
SELECT t4.serialNum
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t2.profileID= t1.profileID
  INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3
    ON t3.typeID = t2.typeID
  INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4
    ON t4.timestamp = t3.timestamp AND
       t4.reference = t3.reference
  WHERE t1.profileID = <something>
```

### EDIT

And given that you know you've got a `profileID` value you don't really need to go after `TABLE1`, and can abbreviate the query to:

```
SELECT t4.serialNum
  FROM TABLE2 t2
  INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3
    ON t3.typeID = t2.typeID
  INNER JOIN TABLE4 t4
    ON t4.timestamp = t3.timestamp AND
       t4.reference = t3.reference
  WHERE t2.profileID = <something>
```